# JavaScript that tell a video to start at one second instead of zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've a video on HTML page using iframe and I'm looking for JavaScript or jQuery to start a video from 2. seconds instead of zero. Because a a video preview look black on the screen instead of seeing people on it as preview before you click to play.

This is a HTML script:

```
<iframe width="111" height="63" src="video/videoclip.m4v" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is iphone app using html, css and JS.

Comment: You should be using an html5 video tag, not an iframe.

Comment: this is iphone app using html, css and JS. I've tried html5 video tag but its rubbish to work and in the end I used iframe because it worked better to scale a preview small and when press to play and a normal video plays perfect.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @Jay Blanchard - This is a genuine question and yes, I've tried, spent days and weeks at it weeks ago. I'm asking a genuine question because I needed it. I'm continuing learning and evolving. I'm not here to "p*ss off anyone".

Comment: Here's your answer: You can't control the video player that would be displayed through an iframe.

Comment: If you can use the video tag, you can control start times. With the iframe you can not do that.

Comment: Thank you guys. Can you use JavaScript to manipulate iframe?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the [HTML5 Video](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) tag and JavaScript

```
<video id="videoClip" width="111" height="63" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="video/videoclip.m4v" type="video/m4v">
</video>
```

This JavaScript will wait until the video is loaded, then start at 2 sec.

```
document.getElementById('videoClip').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 2;
}, false);
```

The video tag can be styled using CSS to make it look like you iframe solution.

Comment: Type might be: type="video/mp4" I am not sure what m4v uses.

Comment: Thank you Eystein. Does it work as video preview on a small screen e.g. width="111" height="63" and a user click a video play icon and it open when clicked (onTouch for iPhone), then plays on a iphone full screen e.g. 480x320 on iphone 4s?

Comment: Yes you can add a onClick event and then do: document.getElementById('videoClip').webkitEnterFullscreen();